# SQL Server - Multiple select queries hit performance

Tags: sql-server

Recently I ran into an issue where we have multiple concurrent client requests causing performance issue in db. I tried the test scenario and as it turned out, when I run SELECT queries (same query) 6 to 7 times (gets worse with more), It degrades the performance and execution takes a lot of time. However I tried this one

```
SELECT TOP (100) COUNT(DISTINCT([Doc_Number])) AS "Expression" 
FROM (
   SELECT * 
   FROM "dbo"."Dummy_Table" "table_alias" 
   WHERE ((CAST("table_alias"."ID" AS NVARCHAR)) NOT IN 
   (
      SELECT "PrimaryKey" AS ExceptionKey 
      FROM dbo.exceptions inner_exceptionStatus 
      LEFT JOIN dbo.Workflow inner_workflowStates ON 
         (inner_exceptionStatus."Status"= inner_workflowStates."UUID" AND 
          inner_exceptionStatus."UUID"= 'CA1662D6-73A2-4692-A765-E7E3EDB66062') 
      WHERE ("inner_workflowStates"."RemoveFromRecordSet" = 1 AND 
              "inner_workflowStates"."IsDeleted" = 0) AND 
            ("inner_exceptionStatus"."IsArchived" IS NULL OR 
            "inner_exceptionStatus"."IsArchived" = 0)))) wrapperQuery
```

The query when runs alone takes around 1sec execution time. But If we runs it in parallel, for each query it takes up a wried amount of time of leads to timeout.
The only thing bothers me here is that SELECT query should be non-blocking and even with shared lock, then need to get along easily.

I am not sure if there is anything wrong in the query that adds up the situation.

Any help is deeply appreciated !!

Comment: For such questions, please provide execution plan.

Comment: Your shouldn't really be using `WHERE ((CAST("table_alias"."ID" AS NVARCHAR)) NOT IN`. In case there's any NULL values in the inner select, your query stops returning any rows. You should use `not exists(select ...` instead

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT( [Doc_Number] )) AS Expression
FROM   dbo.Dummy_Table table_alias
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   dbo.exceptions inner_exceptionStatus
                          INNER JOIN dbo.Workflow inner_workflowStates
                                  ON ( inner_exceptionStatus.Status = inner_workflowStates.UUID
                                       AND inner_exceptionStatus.UUID = 'CA1662D6-73A2-4692-A765-E7E3EDB66062' )
                   WHERE  inner_workflowStates.RemoveFromRecordSet = 1
                          AND inner_workflowStates.IsDeleted = 0
                          AND ( inner_exceptionStatus.IsArchived IS NULL
                                 OR inner_exceptionStatus.IsArchived = 0 )
                          AND table_alias.ID = PrimaryKey)
```

Made couple of changes.

- Changed `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS`
- Removed the convert in `"table_alias"."ID"` because it will avoid using any index present in `"table_alias"."ID"` column. If the conversion is really required then add it.
- Removed `Top (100)` since there is no `Group By` it will return a single record as result.

Still if the query is running slow then you need to post the `execution plan` and make sure the `statistics` are *up-to-date*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I tried with the suggested query, It seems to be running really fast. But the concurrency issue is still there. It's just when I run same query in series, each query takes around 300ms but In case I hit this 20 times simultaneously, the time per each query goes up to 4secs.

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal - for 20 simultaneous hits 4 secs sounds reasonable. Anyway how many records present in each table ? What are the available indexes ? Are they getting used ?

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal - Is `Doc_Number` unique in `Dummy_Table` If yes remove the `distinct` in `count`

Comment: I don't think the table has any index. It is just a test scenario. To be frank the table may be huge and not completely optimized for querying purpose. But this is something I don't have any authority on. So, Things to worry is do you have any idea why for 20 simultaneous query, each query takes up around 20 times more time? or how SQL server handles parallel query execution.

Comment: For a novice, I think even if we start 20 parallel connection with same query, It would evaluate in well time as individual query. I don't think memory is a restriction here.

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal - I think each session will have its own data pages in memory though the data pages are same but I am not sure on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplyfy your query like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Doc_Number)) AS Expression 
FROM dbo.Dummy_Table dmy 
WHERE not exists
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM dbo.exceptions ies 
   INNER JOIN dbo.Workflow iws ON ies.Status= iws.UUID AND ies.UUID= 'CA1662D6-73A2-4692-A765-E7E3EDB66062' 
   WHERE iws.RemoveFromRecordSet = 1 AND iws.IsDeleted = 0 AND (ies.IsArchived IS NULL OR ies.IsArchived = 0)
   and dmy.ID=PrimaryKey

)
```

Like prdp say :

1. Changed NOT IN to NOT EXISTS
2. Removed the convert in "table_alias"."ID" because it will avoid using any index present in "table_alias"."ID" column. If the conversion is really required then add it.
3. Removed Top (100) since there is no Group By it will return a single record as result.

I add :

1. Remove you temporary table wrapperQuery
2. You can use INNER JOIN because into where you test RemoveFromRecordSet = 1 then you remove null values.
3. Remove not utils quotes ,brackets and parenthèses into where clause